# is there a "About box" of Java swing in C#?

Tags: c#, java, .net, swing, about-box

I'm looking for an control or something like to About box [Java Swing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_%28Java%29) in C#.

**UPDATE**
as in the pic:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "about box"?

Comment: The equivalent in a C# Windows Forms should be dialog box, have a look here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx

Comment: you'll probably have to create your own winform about box. That's what I do when I need one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you're using VS, choose in menu: `project` > `add new item` > `about box` in visual studio installed templates.

and then:

```
 var aboutBox = new AboutBox1();
 aboutBox.ShowDialog();
```

I hope this help!